# fancybox 1.3.4 resize pic to fix iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox

I have fancybox 1.3.4 and am trying to have a picture shrunk down to fit my iframe and cant figure out how to do it. Right now I have the big picture loaded in the iframe but you have to scroll around the frame to see the whole pick
 Like this:

[image]

my code looks like this:

```
 $.fancybox({
    'title': title,
    'titlePosition': 'inside',
    'width'  : 600,           // set the width
    'height' : 600,           // set the height
    'type'   : 'iframe' ,      // tell the script to create an iframe
    'href':res,

    });
```

Comment: what is the value of `res`? does the image have to be inside an iframe?

Comment: @JFK the value of res is just the <img source= 'mypic.jpg'> and no i just want the popup

Comment: then just remove `'type':'iframe'` from your code

Comment: @JFK WOW I spent way too long trying to figure that out.. Thank you! Add this as a answer and ill accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display images in fancybox, you don't need to set `type: "iframe"` neither the `width` or `height` since fancybox will automatically detect those settings for you[1], so this should be enough

```
$.fancybox({
    'title': title,
    'titlePosition': 'inside',
    //'width'  : 600,           // set the width
    //'height' : 600,           // set the height
    //'type'   : 'iframe' ,      // tell the script to create an iframe
    'href': res,
});
```

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wwA5f/)</kbd>

[1] **Note**: the targeted images should have a valid image extension (.jpg, .png, .gif) otherwise `type:"image"` would be required. See http://fancybox.net/faq No.6 for more information